# Which headers and DLL files do I need to use IDL_DRSWriteSPN in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, rpc

I'm new to Windows API and RPC programming. I'm trying to create a simple program that uses

```
IDL_DRSWriteSPN
```

function to register a new SPN. The function itself is straightforward, but I'm getting compilation errors in Visual Studio.
Here's a snippet of the code:

```
// Create the request message
DRS_MSG_SPNREQ msgIn;
msgIn.V1.pwszAccount = pwszAccount;
msgIn.V1.operation = DS_SPN_ADD_SPN_OP;
msgIn.V1.cSPN = 1;
msgIn.V1.rpwszSPN = &pwszSPN;

// Create the response message
DRS_MSG_SPNREPLY msgOut;
DWORD dwOutVersion = 0;

// Call IDL_DRSWriteSPN
dwRet = IDL_DRSWriteSPN(hDrs, 1, &msgIn, &dwOutVersion, &msgOut);
```

The problem is the compiler doesn't recognize DRS_MSG_SPNREQ or IDL_DRSWriteSPN.

I included the following header files, but that didn't fix the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ntdsapi.h>
```

My understanding is that Drsuapi types and functions should be included in `Drsupai.h`, but I can't find the header file or the DLL where the function is implemented (presumably drsupai.dll) in Windows SKD. What am I missing here?

Comment: take [idl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-drsr/3f5d9495-9563-44de-876a-ce6f880e3fb2) and compile it. and you got header